# Failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" to obtain schema: unknown provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, init

**Error message:**

> Error while installing hashicorp/aws v4.21.0: open .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\aws\4.21.0\windows_amd64\terraform-provider-aws_v4.21.0_x5.exe: The system cannot find the path specified.`

[image]
[image]

**Initializing the backend:**

> Installing hashicorp/aws v4.21.0...
> ╷│ Error: Failed to install provider││ Error while installing hashicorp/aws v4.21.0: open .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\aws\4.21.0\windows_amd64\terraform-provider-aws_v4.21.0_x5.exe: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is a file at the path Terraform mentioned in the error message here? That would help to understand whether the problem is that the file isn't present or whether it's present but Terrafom cannot open it for some reason.

Comment: As discussed in [a question about a similar error](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-os-error/b7be3794-9144-46ca-97ea-0ae26bdf6208), by default Windows has a maximum path length and if you exceed it the operating system will return "The system cannot find the path specified" as you saw here. Therefore if you can see that the file is in the location Terraform is looking, my suggestion would be to use a working directory at a shorter path -- perhaps a subdirectory directly in your mingw64 home directory -- to see if that helps.